# How to select all the second Saturdays of the current year?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(NEXT_DAY((TRUNC(TO_DATE('01-JAN-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),
                                'MONTH') - 1),
                         'SATURDAY'),
                'SATURDAY') SECOND_SATURDAY
  FROM DUAL;
```

The above query shows only the given month's Second Saturday date

But i want to retrieve all the Second Saturdays of the Current Year.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Minor* enhancement to your version, by first generating `first day` of ALL months and then use that in your query.

```
WITH ALL_MONTHS AS
(SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01-JAN-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),LEVEL-1) as MONTH_FIRST_DATE 
 FROM DUAL
 CONNECT BY LEVEL<=12)
SELECT NEXT_DAY(NEXT_DAY((TRUNC(MONTH_FIRST_DATE,
                                'MONTH') - 1),
                         'SATURDAY'),
                'SATURDAY') SECOND_SATURDAY
  FROM ALL_MONTHS;
```

ALL Saturdays!!

```
WITH ALL_SATURDAYS AS
  (SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01012014','DDMMYYYY'),'WW')                              * (level)                                                                                       AS WEEK_NO,
    NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE('01012014','DDMMYYYY')                                         + (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01012014','DDMMYYYY'),'WW' ) * (level-1) * 7),'SAT')                        AS SATURDAY_DATE,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE('01012014','DDMMYYYY') + (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01012014','DDMMYYYY'),'WW' ) * (level-1) * 7),'SAT'),'MON') ORDER BY level) AS Pos
  FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY level<= 52
  ORDER BY 1
  )
SELECT SATURDAY_DATE,POS FROM ALL_SATURDAYS WHERE POS IN (2,4) ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: Great @OracleUser.. May i know how to find the 2nd and 4th Saturdays for all the 12 months...